# Running mock more than once

Tags: c#, .net, nunit, moq

I was suggested following Mocking to test some method. I have to run this mock multiple times like 5. I am wondering if it can be done in lambda expression or I have to loop it through. 
Thanks

```
//when you know the parameter values to expect
mockEmailRequest.Verify(r=>r.EmailRecevied(expectedEmail, expectedId));

//when you just want to verify some detail about the values
mockEmailRequest.Verify(r=>r.EmailRecevied(It.Is<EmailResponse>(r=>r.Subject ==  "Something"),   It.Is<int>(i=>i > 17)));
```

Comment: there is Mock.VerifyAll(). Not sure that it will work or not,

Comment: You question is not clear. What do you want to verify? Whether you called the `EmailRecevied` 5 times with a given set of parameters?

Comment: Yes I want to verify if EmailRecevied was call 5 times for given set of parameters. Thanks

Comment: Take a look at my answer please

Answer (score 0):

You should use this code:

```
mockEmailRequest.Verify(r=>r.EmailRecevied(It.Is<EmailResponse>(r=>r.Subject ==  "Something"), It.Is<int>(i=>i > 17)), Times.Exactly(5));
```